# "Общество не одобрило бы этого шага" или "общество не одобрило бы этот шаг"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как лучше сказать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Варианты равноправны. В живой речи более естественной выглядит форма родительного падежа (этого шага).

Answer (score 0):

Специалисты по стилистике (Солганик, Дроняева) отмечают, что конструкции с родительным падежом при глаголе с отрицанием в современном языке приобрели книжный характер. Родительный падеж, по их мнению,  употребляется главным образом у существительных отвлеченных  или в устойчивых оборотах типа *не обращать внимания*. Голуб отмечает, что употребление родительного падежа при глаголе с отрицанием усиливает отрицание, тогда как винительный "приглушает" его. В Вашем случае, на мой взгляд, лучше употребить винительный падеж: *общество не одобрило бы этот шаг*, поскольку наличествует сослагательное наклонение, снижающее резкость высказывания.